# How to use GROUP BY with a substring of a DATE-like column value?

Tags: php, mysql, date, group-by, substring

I have a query that joins 2 tables to generate a certain result:

```
select users.*, membership.* from users join membership on membership.id = user.m_id
```

The problem is that I need to count all the users and group them by year (their register year) so that I can see user count for each year.

The date is not stored as a date format, I have used `varchar` because we save only the `year` and `month` as  year/month. ex: `2017/05`

On the `users` table I have a field called `join_month`. So is it possible to split the value in `join_month` and group the value by the year?

Comment: You should store it as a datetime, then format as needed on output. `2017` as a varchar is just a string, as a datetime you could use `year()` to get just the year. Something like `select count(userid), year(joindate) from users group by year(joindate)`.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like your database structure does not serve you well.

You could:

- use `SUBSTRING_INDEX()` to split and access the desired substrings
- normalize your date data by having a year and a month column
- store the date data as DATE type and just default the day portion to `01` and use YEAR() when querying.

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible to split text values like `2016/05` from the join_month and group the value by the year?

Of course. Use `LEFT(join_month, 4)` to pull the first four characters from your  `date_month` columns. If you're confident your `join_month` strings contain consistent data this will work just fine. Just say `GROUP BY LEFT(join_month, 4)` in your query

However, your life would be probably be easier if you could use date arithmetic on these columns.  This expression will get you a DATE value for the first day in your `date_month` columns.

```
  DATE(CONCAT(LEFT(date_month, 4), '-', RIGHT (date_month, 2), '-01'))
```

It's useful because then you can do stuff like

```
  DATE(CONCAT(LEFT(date_month, 4), '-', RIGHT (date_month, 2), '-01')) - INTERVAL 1 QUARTER
```

if you need date offsetting.